# CSS: Expanding a floating element's width based on its contents

Tags: javascript, html, css

A colleague of mine was working on a CSS design which contains an un-ordered list (`<ul>` tag) that has its `<li`> tags floated to right.

Each list item contains a `<div>` (non-floating) which contains an image and a paragraph.

The inner `<div>`'s width is being changed when hovering above it (using a jQuery animation effect).

The problem is that when the `<div>`'s width is changed, it goes outside of the `<li>` bounds.

Generally speaking, is there a way to expand or shrink a floating element based on its content elements' maximum width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't set any width on the LI or the UL and it will expand. Floated elements automatically "shrink-wrap" around their content - unless so specifically request otherwise by setting a height or width.

Comment: Well, I don't have any width or height on either the li and the ui tags, and it still doesn't work...

Comment: @MikeyS. Can you post an example? If it's small you can just edit your question. If it's larger then use http://jsfiddle.net/ - or post the url of your site.

Comment: There must be some other style overriding the natural behaviour then, as Ariel is spot on.

Comment: Well by looking at the Chrome Developer Tools style section, there's no width attribute for the LI elements i'm inspecting

Comment: Ok, well after trying to solve this out after a few hours, I figured it out: The <li> contained a <div> (1) which was assigned a fixed width, inside <div> (1) was another <div> (2) which was the one that had it's width changed dynamically, so based on your comment, that behaviour is kinda expected (since elements will strech to fit contents unless assigned a fixed width). I changed <div> (1)'s width property to min-width instead, and suddenly it all worked like a charm. Unfortunately, I'm not sure that min-width is supported by all browsers... but that's another story...

Comment: @MikeyS. You can easily work around min-width - just put a spacer image in there of the min-width. Or an empty div with that width.